# Encrypt a file and destroy all unencrypted copies

Tags: security, gnupg

I have a text file with various passwords, usernames and financial information on it. Suppose I want to encrypt it, then rsync copies to various devices. If I use GPG to encrypt the file, how can I guarantee there is no unencrypted copy of the file left behind on the HDD or in RAM?

Does that make sense?

I want to encrypt a file (no problem), then make sure there is no way to access the file at all.

Comment: There is no guarantee that you can keep the intelligence services of the superpower nations from reading your secrets. But you can make it very difficult for people with less muscles ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that makes sense. Someone stealing your HDD could perform a forensic analysis and might find your original file. This is very unlikely though. If this is a real concern for you, you can use `shred`.

With RAM, I suppose the risk vanishes once you power off your computer.

Comment: And even with shred, there's a fair chance that the files content at some point might have been swapped, a program has written a backup file (like emacs does), the file system has moved it on disk etc etc etc. If you need security against someone having your disk, use full disk encryption, or physically destroy the drive in question.

Answer (score 0):

### LVM with encryption alias encrypted disk

Maybe the best way to keep things secret is to install Ubuntu according to this test case,

[Install Ubuntu to the entire disk with lvm and encryption](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/363/builds/126272/testcases/1451/results)

and do the secret tasks in this system. Encrypted copies can be rsynced to other systems, which are not encrypted.

**Comments**

This kind of system is as vulnerable to attacks via the internet connection as any other system. So be very cautious when browsing the internet etc. And shut down the system, when you are not using it.

You can `shred` the original files, but with journaling (which is used in a modern operating system), there is no guarantee, that all temporary copies are overwritten.

It is difficult or sometimes even impossible to recover a damaged encrypted system, so it is very important to have a good backup routine (to take backups at regular intervals, and to keep the backup copy in a place that is safe against theft, flood and fire.

Use a good password and remember it. There is no back door ;-)